# Prolog Program output

Tags: prolog

I am a newbie in programming and I came across a program, which I tried to execute on SWI_PROLOG and couldn't understand how the output was generated. If someone could help me walk through the steps of how `c(X,Y,Z).` is evaluated it would help a lot. The program is

```
a(1).
a(2).
b(a).
c(A,B,C):- a(A), d(B,C).
c(A,B,C):- b(A), d(B,C).
d(B,C):- a(B), !, a(C).
d(B,_):- b(B).
```

OUTPUT:

```
X = Y, Y = Z, Z = 1 .
```

Comment: it's better to learn to use system facilities: try `?- trace.` and then `?- c(X,Y,Z).`. Follow step by step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

? - c(X,Y,Z).
1. call c(X,Y,Z) // where `c(A,B,C):- a(A), d(B,C)`.
2. call a(X) // which is the first rule --> it evaluates to 1 because of fact a(1) so X is 1
3. call d(Y,Z) // where `d(B,C):- a(B), !, a(C)`
4. call a(Y) // Y evaluates to 1 so Y is 1.
5. call a(Z) // Z evaluates to 1 so Z is 1.

So d(B,C) is d(1,1), we found out that a(A) is a(1) so
c(1, 1, 1) => X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1.

If you press **;** you will be able to find more solutions.